# Prove that $\dfrac {2x+y+z}{x}+\dfrac {2y+x+z}{y}+\dfrac {2z+x+y}{z}\ge 12$

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove that

$$\dfrac {2x+y+z}{x}+\dfrac {2y+x+z}{y}+\dfrac {2z+x+y}{z}\ge 12$$

Clearly

$2x+y+z>x, \ 2y+x+z>y, 2z+x+y>z$

However, I struggle to find a suitable inequality relation to move further on here. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: You should tell us where $x,y,z$ live--are they real numbers? Also, please show any work you've initially done.

Comment: That is right, $x,\ y,\ z \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Hint: the LHS is related to $(x+y+z)(1/x + 1/y + 1/z)$.

Comment: @NickF 
Now we can re-write this to 

$$\dfrac{(x^2 y + x^2 z + x y^2 + 6 x y z + x z^2 + y^2 z + y z^2)}{x y z}\geq 12$$

and since we have the following equality:

$$(x+y+z)(1/x+1/y+1/z)=\frac{(x + y + z) (x y + x z + y z)}{x y z}$$  We can further develop it. But how do we go on from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SEE
(2x+y+z)/x = (x+y+z+x)/x = {(x+y+z)/x}+1
similarly do this for other numbers
you will obtain

(x+y+z)(1/x + 1/y + 1/z) + 3 by am-hm inequality
this is greater than equal to 12
Hence Proved

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How do you actually show that $(x+y+z)(1/x + 1/y + 1/z) + 3\geq 12$ here?

Answer (score 4):

LHS = $3 + (x+y+z)(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}) \ge 3 + 9 = 12$ by AM-HM inequality.

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: Get what? The first line or the inequality?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities

Comment: PS: I  can't see how you go from $\dfrac{(x^2 y + x^2 z + x y^2 + 6 x y z + x z^2 + y^2 z + y z^2)}{x y z}\geq 12$ to your inequality.

Comment: $\frac{2x+y+z}{x} = 1 + \frac{x+y+z}{x}$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: No, do the same thing to each of the three terms, that's where the 3 comes from and you are left with $(x+y+z)(1/x+1/y+1/z)$.

Comment: I got  now  

$$\dfrac {2x+y+z}{x}=\frac{y/2}{x} + \frac{z/2 }{x} + 1,$$

$$\dfrac {2y+x+z}{2y}=\frac{x/2}{y}+ \frac{z/2}{y}+ 1,$$

$$\dfrac {2z+x+y}{2z}=\frac{x/2}{z} + \frac{y/2}{z} + 1$$
  but how did you get 9?